# How to swap command and option modifier keys with a script in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript

I use a PC usb keyboard with my macbook. So, I've gone into `System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys`... and swapped command and option for the usb keyboard. This puts those keys in the "correct" position for a mac.

But, for part of the day, I remote desktop to a windows machine. So now, I need to swap the keys back, so the remote desktop client isn't confused.

It's easy enough to do this through the **Preferences** UI, but its cumbersome.

I'd like to use a script of some kind (maybe applescript), so I could  quickly swap back and forth.

I've found several scripts online, but none of them are for Lion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to modify some of the scripts already out there, and get them to work in Lion. To create these scripts:

- Run the Applescript Editor
- Create two new empty script files (command-N)
- Paste in these two scripts
- Save them as something like "swap command option" and "restore command option" or whatever you'd like
- You can test them by running them in the applescript editor.

Here is the script to swap command to option, and option to command:

```
#
# Script to swap the Command and Option keys
# in the System Preferences Keyboard settings.
#
# Helpful if using a PC keyboard
#

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
    click button "Modifier Keys…" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"

    # Select keyboard: pop up button
    click pop up button 5 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    # The 4th choice there.. my USB Keyboard
    click menu item 4 of menu 1 of pop up button 5 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    # The Option Key pop up
    click pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    # Change it to Command, the 4th choice
    click menu item 4 of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    # The Command Key pop up
    click pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    # Change it to Option, the 3rd choice
    click menu item 3 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    click button "OK" of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

Here is the script to swap them back:

```
#
# Script to restore the Command and Option keys to their defaults 
# in the System Preferences Keyboard settings.
#

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
    click button "Modifier Keys…" of tab group 1 of window "Keyboard"

    # Select keyboard: pop up button
    click pop up button 5 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    # The 4th choice there.. my USB Keyboard
    click menu item 4 of menu 1 of pop up button 5 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    # The Option Key pop up
    click pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    # Change it to Option, the 3rd choice
    click menu item 3 of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    # The Command Key pop up
    click pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"
    # Change it to Command, the 4th choice
    click menu item 4 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    click button "OK" of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"

    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

To make these scripts easy to access, you can go to Applescript Editor Preferences and check "Show Script menu in menu bar". Then, copy your scripts to your home directory Library/Scripts directory, i.e. /Users/ryan/Library/Scripts

Now you can access them right off the menu bar script menu.

Comment: Thanks for this! In Catalina, it looks like Option is pop up button 4 but the rest worked more or less as-is.

Comment: I also found `click button "Restore Defaults" of sheet 1 of window "Keyboard"` a more elegant / generic way to go back to defaults, assuming you don't tend to mess with any of the other mappings.

Comment: On my machine, there is enough delay before the Keyboard preference pane finishes loading that the `window "Keyboard"` reference will fail with `Can’t get window "Keyboard" of process "System Preferences". ` You can quick fix this by adding `delay 1` before the System Events tell. In theory it's possible to script out a wait and check for the window to be loaded...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <not>REMOTEDESKTOPCONNECTION</not>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

`REMOTEDESKTOPCONNECTION` is defined in [appdef.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/appdef.xml).

This would make fn-escape toggle swapping option and command:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::ESCAPE, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::VK_CONFIG_TOGGLE_swapoptcmd</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>swapoptcmd</name>
    <identifier vk_config="true">swapoptcmd</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```