# How can I map the Windows key to option in Microsoft Remote Desktop version 8?

Tags: remote-desktop

In Remote Desktop Connection version 2.x you could map the remote windows key to the local option key (instead of the command key) in preferences. In the new Microsoft Remote Desktop version 8 from the App Store I can no longer find this setting. Is this feature tucked away somewhere and I'm missing it?

One option might be KeyRemapForMacbook as discussed [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/105118), but I want to know if there is a solution that doesn't require third party software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this appears to no longer be possible without 3<sup>rd</sup>-party software.

Adding the same preference key to the new app seemed to not make any difference - it appears that this ability has been removed from the app.

As you mentioned, KeyRemap4Macbook would work with the private.xml that you linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the private.xml I ended up using in KeyRemap4Macbook to remap the keys. In particular note that I set it up so that the physical command-tab combination still activates app switching just like in the old version of RDP. Note that you must also enable the existing "Shift_L to Lazy_Shift_L" and "Shift_R to Lazy_Shift_R" options to enable using command-shift-tab to navigate backwards while switching apps.

```
<appdef>
    <appname>MRD</appname>
    <equal>com.microsoft.rdc.mac</equal> 
</appdef>
<item>
    <name>Swap command and option in Remote Desktop</name>
    <identifier>private.remotedesktopswapcommandandcontrol</identifier>
    <only>MRD</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
</item>
```