# Unmap key combinations in KeyRemap4Macbook

Tags: macos, keyboard, remote-desktop

This is a follow up to [How can I map the Windows key to option in Microsoft Remote Desktop version 8?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108586/how-can-i-map-the-windows-key-to-option-in-microsoft-remote-desktop-version-8). The answers to that question are a huge timesavers for OSX RDC users; however, there are some key combinations I don't want remapped. For example, Command+Q and Command+W would ideally still function the same as they do before remapping.

I tried adding this definition:

```
<autogen>
    __KeyToKey__ 
    KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, 
    KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
</autogen>
```

But to no effect.

**Update:** here is the full `private.xml`:

```
<root>
    <appdef>
        <appname>Microsoft Remote Desktop</appname>
        <equal>com.microsoft.rdc.mac</equal> 
    </appdef>
    <item>
        <name>Swap command and option in Remote Desktop</name>
        <identifier>private.remotedesktopswapcommandandcontrol</identifier>
        <only>Microsoft Remote Desktop</only>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__ 
            KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, 
            KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
        </autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation suggests that these shouldn't conflict:

```
<autogen>
   __KeyToKey__
   KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
   KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE,
</autogen>
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
```

However, the second `<autogen>` will override the `COMMAND_L` of the first. The solution is counterintuitive:

```
<root>
    <appdef>
        <appname>Microsoft Remote Desktop</appname>
        <equal>com.microsoft.rdc.mac</equal> 
    </appdef>
    <item>
        <name>Swap command and option in Remote Desktop</name>
        <identifier>private.remotedesktopswapcommandandcontrol</identifier>
        <only>Microsoft Remote Desktop</only>            
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, MODIFIERFLAG_EITHER_LEFT_OR_RIGHT_OPTION, KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::Q, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE,
            KeyCode::Q, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
        </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

In this case `Cmd+Q` is remapped to `Opt+Q` but then `Opt+Q` is remapped back to `Cmd+Q'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add that autogen before the others:

> #### Order of <autogen>
>
> **Basic case**
>   KeyRemap4MacBook applies only the first matched `<autogen>`.

<sup>Source: https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en</sup>

---

Try…

```
<autogen>
  __KeyToKey__
  KeyCode::Q, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
  KeyCode::Q, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L
</autogen>
```

Comment: I tried that after reading the docs, but it doesn't seem to work. I updated the question to include the full XML I'm using.

Comment: See edit (@wst)

Comment: It seems (contrary to what the docs suggest) that `__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L` will always override `KeyCode::Q, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE`. I was actually able to get it working with the counterintuitive `__KeyToKey__
                KeyCode::Q, VK_OPTION | ModifierFlag::NONE,
                KeyCode::Q, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,` **at the END**. If you have a better solution, let me know. Or just update your answer with that, and I'll accept for the assist.

Comment: @wst Interesting! That does seem strange, or I'm overlooking something… Feel free to self-answer — I don't think I could explain it as well as you and I wouldn't want to take credit.